# How do I obtain the value of the option that was chosen in a select from?

Tags: php, mysql

In the PHP code below I have created a form that is used to create a drop down list.

```
<?php
echo "<body>";
echo "<div id='network_name' class='col-md-3'>";
echo "<h2> Agency Network </h2>";
echo "<form action='droplistpop.php' method='post'>";
echo "<select name='network'>";
while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    unset($network_id, $network_name);
    $network_id = $network_name['network_id'];
    $network_name = $result1['network_code'];
    echo '<option name="entry" value="' . $network_id . '">' . $network_name . '</option>';
    $network_chosen = $network_id;

}

echo "</select>";
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Send' />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

This code works as desired. It populates a drop down list based on the results of a database query. After the form has been submitted, I want to obtain the option that was selected and use it in another query. After the submit, I print the contents of the $_POST variable using:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and my results are as follow:
Array ( [network] => [submit] => Send )

I want to get the value that was selected for network but it appears to be blank. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

By the way, I am really new at coding and this is my first time using SO so please excuse any usage errors on my part. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain `$network_id = $network_name['network_id'];`?

Comment: Look at the source code of the generated select block. Does the value show up there correctly?

Comment: Are you submitting this form normally or is there some Ajax involved somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

`$network_id = $result1['network_id'];`
    instead of 
`$network_id = $network_name['network_id']`

Output like this:

```
Array ( [network] => 2 [submit] => Send )
```

Comment: I made the suggested change and that did the job!!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a wrong value to network_id, that's why it's output is blank. Also, the 'name' attribute on option tags is not needed. Try the changes below.

```
<?php
echo "<body>";
echo "<div id='network_name' class='col-md-3'>";
echo "<h2> Agency Network </h2>";
echo "<form action='droplistpop.php' method='post'>";
echo "<select name='network'>";
while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    unset($network_id, $network_name);
    $network_id = $result1['network_id'];
    $network_name = $result1['network_code'];
    echo '<option value="' . $network_id . '">' . $network_name . '</option>';
    $network_chosen = $network_id;

}

echo "</select>";
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Send' />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```